# How to prevent caller from catching my exceptions

Tags: java

I wrote a `safeMethod()` which should not throw any exceptions, and if it does, I want to crash the app (to get them reported via crash monitoring system).

The problem is, I need to call this method from [library callback](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/WebSocketListener.kt#L29) which is [wrapped in `try/catch` up the call stack](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/ws/RealWebSocket.kt#L191-L198).

I tried to "raise stakes":

```
try {
    safeMethod();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Throwable(e);
}
```

But this does not compile because overridden method does not declare `throws Throwable`.

The other thing that comes to my mind is to use some asynchrony, for example:

```
new Handler().post(() -> safeMethod());  // Handler is Android class to work with thread's message queue
```

or

```
new Thread(() -> safeMethod()).start();
```

It works, but seems like an overkill, complicating control flow and wasting resources.

Are there any better ways?

I searched here and on the web for "prevent catching exception", "override catch block", "force throw exception" and so on, but found nothing relevant. Not even unanswered questions. Numerous advices to catch only specific exceptions are not very useful in this case. ;)

Comment: You can also "raise stakes" by throwing an implementation of `Error`. That does not require you to declare a throws clause IIRC.

Comment: I'm questioning why you want an error that is otherwise handled gracefully to cause the application to terminate.

Comment: @Sweeper `Error` works, thanks. :)  Will you post it as an answer?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Because I would like to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). 
I recently discovered there were some bugs, swallowed by this `try/catch` for months, instead of being reported to Crashlytics and promptly fixed.

Comment: Well, blowing up the entire system sure is a fast way to fail. Personally though, i'd refactor the exception handling so it, you know, properly handles the exception.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I catch all expected exceptions (oxymoron? ;)) inside `safeMethod` and handle them "properly". So anything that bubbles up means a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest two options:

1. Throw an `Error`
2. `System.exit(1);`

It is up to you which one to choose the main difference is that throwing an error will give you a stack trace and then do `System.exit(1)`.

It is important to call `System.exit` with something different then 0 to show an error situation.

Normally it is not recommended to throw Errors but your case might be an exception from that rule.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get these exceptions reported via crash monitoring system. I edited my question to reflect this. `System.exit(1)` does not do the job, while `throw new Error(e)` works fine. Thanks.